# Двусторонная синхронизация БД FireBird и PostgreSQL

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, firebird

Есть две БД: FireBird и PostgreSQL.

В FireBird хранится вся информация. В PostgreSQL нужно передать только некоторые таблицы для работы с ними. Если будут какие либо изменения в одной из БД, то следует их передать и в другую БД.

Вопрос - как это сделать?

Comment: Добавлять новые записи в синхронизируемых таблицах могут с обеих сторон? Что делать, если запись изменили в обеих БД? Базы имеют постоянную прямую связь, периодическую или могут не иметь связи и нужно промежуточное транспортное хранилище?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, добавлять новые записи можно только у одной из сторон. Одну запись не могут изменить сразу 2 бд, сначала участие принимает одна бд, затем другая, возможность конфликта должна равняться нулю по идее. Базы должны иметь постоянную прямую связь, желательно с промежуточным транспортным хранилищем.

Comment: Взять любой репликатор, умеющий работать с PG с одной стороны и другой репликатор, умеющий работать с FB с другой стороны. Например, IBPReplicator для репликации данных из FB в PG и DbLink с триггерами для обратного процесса. Ну или нагуглить один репликатор, умеющий работать в обе стороны. Хотя проще, конечно, будет добавить в базу PG линки на Firebird и не парить моск.

Answer (score 0):

Установить https://github.com/ibarwick/firebird_fdw/blob/master/README.md и импортировать схему. Вуаля, таблицы Firebird доступны в PostgreSQL.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что firebird fdw работает как расширение для postgresql на линуксе?

Comment: @kepeeennnddd Да, именно это и написано в его документации.